# Why did the NATO (help to) overthrow Kadhafi?

Tags: africa, 21st-century, nato

What was NATO's goal? What was the strategic objective?

NATO tolerated Kadhafi when he was quite hardline against the West and attacked him when he took a much more cooperative attitude towards the West.

Comment: I'm not sure political-history tag fits here. It seems to me that this is not the history of a political event, but the politics of an historical event. Or am I picking nits?

Comment: I think @CGCampbell's question is very relevant; if others agree, we may wish to close, edit and re-open to ensure answers are relevant. Could we revise this question to emphasize historical themes and downplay the implicit judgement of politics?  I'm going to attempt an edit; if I get it wrong, please rollback.

Comment: It's a good question, only problem with it is it's too recent. In 10 or 15 years the leaks will come out etc... at the moment it's too recent for there to be any reasonable sources.

Comment: After researching this, I find myself in agreement with @NeMo. There is the public reason given by the UN and NATO, then there are the conspiracies; the truth will likely be somewhere in the middle.